# Can't stop and remove docker containers

Tags: docker

I'm trying to stop and remove some docker containers on my machine, but something really weird is happening here.

I [tried](https://coderwall.com/p/ewk0mq/stop-remove-all-docker-containers) to stop:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
```

This works for a moment, because the `docker ps` shows no container running. But few seconds later the images appear again with a new container ID.

I tried to stop (last command) then remove:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

But I received an error:

> Error: No such container: 0f57644645eb

I also tried this command on the running containers after repeat the stop command:

```
docker update --restart=no container-id
```

The command is successful, but the container are still restarting.

I tried to remove all images after stop them:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

But I received another error:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 0f57644645eb (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container dcef9cdb703c
```

What I'm missing here? I would like to stop and remove these containers to leave Docker as it was after a fresh install.

I'm using Windows 10 and Docker version 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139).

Comment: Are you probably running these containers as a service? You may test with `docker service ls`.

Comment: @Henry, thansk, you found the problem. I used `docker service rm container-id` and the containers finally stopped. I didn't know this "service" concept, because I started this docker containers a long time ago and I not remember what I did. Feel free to add a answer that I will mark as resolved.

Comment: The same behavior can be observed if the containers were started via `docker-compose.yml`. If you have this file present, just use `docker-compose stop`. If it's not the compose file, it's the docker service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour indicates that the container **was started as a service**. The service will try to restart in order to fulfil the specification of running instances.

The services can be checked with `docker service ls`.

It is necessary to remove or reconfigure the service to permanently stop the container.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issues. I just had to `docker service rm containerID` and its finally  gone :D

Answer (score 4):

Could you just try to use the force flag with your removal commands?

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: Hi! The first command works but the second one shows some errors, like: `Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete cb3198f4b4d3 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container c805743b91f3`

Comment: That one should have been removed with the first command I think. What happens if you try to remove it directly, `docker rm -f c80574` ?

Comment: thank you for the contribution. Henry found the problem: I was running as services.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
docker rm CONTAINER_ID
```

Comment: Hi,  I have the same problem. I can not get all containers to stop.  I therefore can not delete a particular docker image because its containers will not stop.  I have tried: FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -aq') DO docker stop %iproblem.  (This is on Windows 10 -  so the regular dollar solution won't work).  FOR starts cycling through the containers deleting them.  But then they come back again.  Is there any docker command that permanently stops them?  I am not running a service. If I do docker service ls I get "This node is not a swarm manager." (And explains how to init or join ).

Comment: You can remove a container, but if it's a service, Docker will simply restart it--that's what's really going on beneath the question here.